# Query for inserting new json String in Saved Json in DB from Java layer

Tags: java, postgresql

We have one column in DB which has saved JSON values in the format of String for ex:

```
{"listOfPlaces" : [1,2,3], "segment" : 1}
```

Now, from the JAVA layer with UPDATE Query we need to update the JSON. 
For ex: we need to add

```
 activityId : 1
```

here in saved JSON of DB.

So that we can have stored JSON as:

```
{"listOfPlaces" : [1,2,3], "segment" : 1, activityId : 1}
```

I tried using code  mentioned below, but not sure it's accurate or not.

```
MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameters.addValue(newFieldName, newFilterCriteriaForAddition.getName());
parameters.addValue(newFieldValue, newFilterCriteriaForAddition.getDefaultValue());
int update = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(Constant.SQL_TO_ADD_FILTER_CRITERIA_IN_SAVED_REPORT, parameters);
```

and Query is :

```
"UPDATE adv.sav_table SET filter_crtr = LEFT(rpt_filter_crtra, -1)  + "||CONCAT("
+ ",\""
+ ":newFieldName:"+":"+newFieldValue"+"}"+") "
```

Comment: *not sure it's accurate or not*:why don't you just... test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for string manipulation:

If that the column is defined as `jsonb` (which it should be), you can simply concatenate the new value:

```
update adv.sav_table 
   SET filter_crtr  = filter_crtr || '{"activityId":1}'
where ...;
```

That can be done through a PreparedStatement:

```
update adv.sav_table 
   SET filter_crtr  = filter_crtr || cast(? as jsonb)
where ...;
```

And then using

```
PreparedStatement pstmt  = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE ...");
psmt.setString(1, "{\"activityId\":1}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get current required field from database which contains JSON,and replace it with new JSON by UPDATE query

and to add new entry in JSON you can try this way ->

var obj = {};

obj = {
"1": "a",
"2": "b"
};

obj["3"] = "c";

Comment: We need to do this in throughout the table in every row. So, Fetching that column first and then adding new entry is not possible.